# How make a list with all download URLs terminating with tar.gz within a web directory

Tags: macos, terminal, download, download-manager

So, I want download all files terminating with tar.gz in this URL per example:
http://ns334561.ip-5-196-65.eu/~fgscenery/WS2.0/

but i need it with format of a list like:

```
http://ns334561.ip-5-196-65.eu/~fgscenery/WS2.0/e000n00.tar.gz
http://ns334561.ip-5-196-65.eu/~fgscenery/WS2.0/e000n10.tar.gz
http://ns334561.ip-5-196-65.eu/~fgscenery/WS2.0/e000n20.tar.gz

...
```

to put in my download manager.

So, how i make that list from the URL above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my problem...

To do that simply install JDownloader, click "Add new address" add in URL/Address Collector the parent URL, in my case: http://ns334561.ip-5-196-65.eu/~fgscenery/WS2.0/, the deselect "auto decompress", in package name, choose a name for the save package/folder, in my case "scenery" and click "next", then in the right hand bar deselect "images" to make sure you only download the tar.gz archives in this case which is the only archive type,

Finally click "Start Download"